# ARM template for logic App to PowerBi with API connection

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

I would like to understand if it possible to automate (or partially automate) the creation of a Logic App connector to Power BI.

basically I would like to automate, as far as it is possible, the connector as described on this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/retail/tutorial-in-store-analytics-export-data-visualize-insights

Power Bi is using an OAUTH authentication hence I am not sure what is like the correct procedure to automate the full process.

I have been looking those resources but I have not found anything related to PowerBi

- https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html
- https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth

Thank you in advance
Marco

Comment: I don't know what you want to do but rather than creating a connector, create an Azure Function and use the SDK's in your chosen language to do what you need.  You can use a service principle.

Comment: @Skin thanks but the problem that I have is how to authenticate Power Bi, not an azure service, from Azure. 
What I need is to create a PowerBi connector from shell. 
This is how it is done suing the UI method:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/retail/tutorial-in-store-analytics-export-data-visualize-insights

Comment: That's what I'm saying, use the REST API's (via whichever SDK you prefer) to authenticate through a service principal.  Do you need to use delegated authority?  If that answer is no, use an application authority.  Also, what do you mean "from shell"?

Comment: This is the C# repo ... https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp

Comment: You can create connector using arm / bicep. The last link you've provided (https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth) should help. So basically you would create the connector then run the powerhsell script that will do the oauth consent.

Comment: You could also use the Power BI API directly and use HTTP action, It will allow you to use a managed identity to connect to PowerBI then you won't have all this trouble.